# Do you still use Eclipse with Android SDK for Android Development?

Tags: android

One of my colleagues, who is a newbie of Android but with many experiences with Java and Eclipse, asked me that is it out-of-date to develop Android with Eclipse + SDK, or Android Studio is just one of options for Android Development?

Is it just a matter of preference, or **should** we use Android Studio for the current Android Development?

Comment: Android Studio is now the only IDE with full support from Google going forward.  However, at the moment it's still for all intents and purposes a beta quality IDE, and NDK support was only recently added in "preview quality".  http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudiowithandroidndkpreviewsupportavailable   If you're just starting out, and working on your own projects that don't require an NDK component, use Android Studio.  Everyone will have to switch over to Android Studio eventually, but for the time being Eclipse is the only fully mature IDE that fully supports the NDK.

Comment: Yes, I do. And still will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Android Developer Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html)

> Important: Support for the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse is ending, per our [announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html). You should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrating to Android Studio.

Personally, I recommend your colleague use Android Studio because it's official recommended by Google now, moreover, pretty easy to use it and believe that he will soon love it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I still use Eclipse for creating library projects.

In Android Studio, projects are always mobile-type projects and there is no project template for library-type projects. If I could just use one IDE for both library and mobile projects that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest both tools can accomplish the same task. I say try it. It is just a matter of preferences and which tool you feel more comfortable. If you've use Eclipse i'll say try out Android Studio.

If you hate you, you can always go back to creating applications in Eclipse. Eclipse may be old but many experts used it before and can improve productivity faster, and save more time,and can get help from many users who uses it.

Comment: ... `If you hate you`? I love me, and still use Eclipse . Loving it.